# jquery show/hide annoucement

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I want to hide my announcement while it is shown and shown while its hidden.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#button_announcement").click(function(){
  $('#announcement').show() ? $('#announcement').hide(300) : $('#announcement').show(300);
  //console.log(announcement);
});
```

Console all the time changes the display value to 'none'.
I'm trying with:

```
$('#announcement').css('display', 'block') ? $('#announcement').hide(300) : $('#announcement').show(300);
```

Also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jquery toogle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to display or hide the matched elements. It is easy to use and no need to have an extra check. Even you can pass duration to animate the transition.

Comment: It works now. Thank you Braj but I'm still wondering why my previous version didn't work? Can someone explain me?

Answer (score 0):

you can use .is(':visible'):

```
$('#announcement').is(':visible') 
    ? $('#announcement').hide(300) 
    : $('#announcement').show(300);
```

Another option is to apply a class then use .hasClass()

Answer (score 0):

As Braj says, just use one of the toggle functions instead.

Here's what was wrong. Your ternary function was checking if $('#announcement').show() was true. It always evaluates to true, that is the function to show the element. You wanted `$('#announcement').is(':visible')`

```js
$("#button_announcement").click(function(){
  $('#announcement').is(':visible') ? $('#announcement').hide(300) : $('#announcement').show(300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button_announcement">Toggle</button>
<div id="announcement">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: In my opinion the best and the shortest version is $('announcement').toggle(300);
It works perfectly and it takes up little space.

Thank you Jason :)

Comment: Agreed. Hope this helped explain what was wrong, and I'm happy to see you going with the least amount of code. `$('#announcement')` with the `#`, right?

Comment: I didn't copy it from my code so i forgot to write `#` before announcement but in the code i have it. Btw sorry for simply question but i'm new in jquery and moreover i have some problems with english but I'm trying as I can!

Comment: Sounds perfect, This site is for people who are trying and have questions.